# Applying functions in single statement for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to sum each i which falls within the range in this 1d data called subset. I wanted to know if I could do this in one line- I get an generator object which I am not sure how I can access when I run the following:

```
print(sum(i) for i in range(0,len(subset)) if -1.00< subset[i] < 1.00)
```

Comment: The `for ... if ...` goes in the `sum` call, not the `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sum` takes an iterable as argument, but you're passing an integer to it. Generators, `range` in Python 3.X for example, are iterable. See below links:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html -> search for "iterable"

Answer (score 3):

you need to do the `sum` over the generator:

```
print(sum(i for i in range(0,len(subset)) if -1.00 < subset[i] < 1.00))
```

your brackets were just set around the wrong items...

a bit more explicit: what you want is this:

```
gen = (i for i in range(0,len(subset)) if -1.00 < subset[i] < 1.00)
print(sum(gen))
```

the way your brackets are set, your result is this:

```
gen = (i for i in range(0,len(subset)) if -1.00 < subset[i] < 1.00)
print(sum(i) for i in gen)
```

...and the expression in the print statement is just another generator.